# Cannot set property as opacity for extrusion layer in mapbox

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I use mapbox 2.10 and react 18.2. I have a mapbox fill-extrusion that gets a filter after a button click

`map.current.setFilter('my-extrude', ['==',["id"] , 0] )`

to show some extruded polygons.

In that layer I try to set a value for each polygon based on a property of the feature.

This doesnt work, I get `Error: The layer 'my-extrude' does not exist in the map's style and cannot be filtered.` probably because of the error in setting the opacity. If I set the opacity to a static number like 0.6, all works well.

What am I missing?

Thanks

```
    map.current.addLayer({'id': 'my-extrude',
    'type': 'fill-extrusion',
    'source': 'my-extrude',
    'paint': { 
      'fill-extrusion-color':[
        'case',
        ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'hover'], false],'rgb(253, 255, 0)',
        ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'click'], false],'rgb(253, 255, 0)',
        'rgb(253, 255, 72)'
      ] ,  
      'fill-extrusion-opacity':['get', 'customTop'],
      'fill-extrusion-height': ['+',['to-number', ['get', 'customTop']] , ['to-number', ['get', 'customHeight']]],   
      'fill-extrusion-base':  ['+',['to-number', ['get', 'customTop']], ['to-number', ['get', 'customBase']]]  
    } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that instead of using 'feature-state' you should create a variable which will get the state of the map element on the page, and if the state is hover then give a static number for that case, and if the state is clicked then give a different static number.

Answer (score 0):

Here most probably because you forgot to convert `customTop` to number just like you did for `fill-extrusion-height` and `fill-extrusion-base` and the error occures because `fill-extrusion-opacity` only accepts numbers between 0 and 1.

```
'fill-extrusion-opacity' : ['to-number', ['get', 'customTop']]
```

**Note also** when you use a `variable` to define `fill-extrusion-opacity` it is recommanded to set it with an interpolate expressions to make `fill-extrusion-opacity` always between 0 and 1.

> **Interpolate** :
> Produces continuous, smooth results by interpolating between pairs of input and output values ("stops"). The input may be any numeric expression (e.g., ["get", "population"]). Stop inputs must be numeric literals in strictly ascending order. The output type must be number, array, or color.

There are multiple ways to [interpolate](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#interpolate) and the one needed here is the `"linear"` type :

> Interpolates linearly between the pair of stops just less than and just greater than the input.

Inspired by this [example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#camera-expressions) from docs that uses the interpolate operator to define a linear relationship between zoom level and circle size using a set of input-output pairs

```
{
 "circle-radius": [
   "interpolate", ["linear"], ["zoom"],
    // zoom is 5 (or less) -> circle radius will be 1px
    5, 1,
    // zoom is 10 (or greater) -> circle radius will be 5px
    10, 5
   ]
}
```

with the same logic :

```
{
 "fill-extrusion-opacity": [
   "interpolate", ["linear"], ['to-number', ['get', 'customTop']],
    // customTop is 0 (or less) -> fill-extrusion-opacity will be 0
    0, 0,
    // customTop is 1 (or greater) -> fill-extrusion-opacity will be 1
    1, 1
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot set the **fill-extrusion-opacity** property with **get** function because it is not a data-driven property. Instead, you need to set it with a static value.

you can set it to a constant value like 0.5 or anything you want to set

```
 map.current.addLayer({
  'id': 'my-extrude',
  'type': 'fill-extrusion',
  'source': 'my-extrude',
  'paint': { 
    'fill-extrusion-color':[
      'case',
      ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'hover'], false],'rgb(253, 255, 0)',
      ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'click'], false],'rgb(253, 255, 0)',
      'rgb(253, 255, 72)'
    ] ,  
    'fill-extrusion-opacity': 0.8, // set it to a constant value
    'fill-extrusion-height': ['+',['to-number', ['get', 'customTop']] , ['to-number', ['get', 'customHeight']]],   
    'fill-extrusion-base':  ['+',['to-number', ['get', 'customTop']], ['to-number', ['get', 'customBase']]]  
  } 
});
```

I hope it should be work